# .htaccess: files with extension declared are redirect to document root

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a strange .htaccess problem that occurs only on one website.

Basically I am trying to remove the .php extension and redirect any page with extension to the same page without one.

This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Remove the slash                                                           |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Redirect to extensionless url                                              |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Pretty urls                                                                |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    # rules here

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So, if I type `website.com/page` it works and displays the page, but `website.com/page.php` redirect me to `http://website.com/var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/page`

This .htaccess works successfully on others shared websites, but this particular one doesn't.

Where is the problem ? Is this depending on some others configuration ? Unfortunately I don't have access to the error logs, this file is all I have.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your extension removing rule to this:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Redirect to extensionless url                                              |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```